# How can I arbitrarily sort a tuple's types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

One thing that really annoys me about C++ is that an empty `struct`/`class` takes up space.

So, I have this idea that `std::tuple` (or some variant, since it's (and the compiler's) implementation is highly implementation dependent) might be able to save the day, which it sort of does, but there are issues due to packing and alignment.  Because of how compilers will align the items in the `struct`, having a empty next to a non-empty next to an empty next to a non-empty will be larger than 2 empties next to 2 non-empties.

Because of this, I need a way to reorder the types based on some criteria.  Sorting the entire list based on size isn't necessary (and may in some cases be detrimental) so I need some generic way to reorder the tuple's type list but still access it as if the type list was in the original order.

I looked around a bit and haven't found anything like this and I'm at a loss.  Ideas on how to accomplish this?

## Example

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
 // Need to be reordered based on some criteria.
std::tuple<A, int, B, float> x;
// In this case move all of the empty objects together like:
//   std::tuple<A, B, int, float> x;
// but still have get<1>(x) return the `int` and get<2>(x) return `B`.
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(get<0>()), A>::value,     "0 should be type A");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(get<1>()), int>::value,   "1 should be type int");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(get<2>()), B>::value,     "2 should be type float");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(get<3>()), float>::value, "3 should be type B");
```

The reason this cannot be done by hand is that this could be part of a template and the elements in tuple may be empty or not, based on the parameters:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D>
class X
{
    // Need to have this auto arranged given some criteria
    // like size or move all of the empties together.
    tuple<A, B, C, D> x;
  public:
    template<int i>
    auto get() -> typename std::tuple_element<i, decltype(x)>
    {
      return get<i>(x);
    }
};
// What are these types?  Who knows.  This could be buried in some
// template library somewhere.
X<T1, T2, T3, T4> x;
```

Comment: Can you reword this question to (a) not be so over-the-top judgmental and (b) ask for a specific thing? The answer to "is there a generic way to reorder the tuple's type list" is "yes", but without more details as to what you actually want to do, we can't really provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Types don't have addresses.

Comment: You are essentially looking for a TMP version of stable-partition.

Comment: See also [`boost::compressed_pair`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/utility/doc/html/compressed_pair.html). It takes advantage of empty base optimization.

Comment: @KerrekSB, what do you mean by a `TMP version of stable-partition`?

Comment: @Adrian: You want something like `Foo<IsEmpty, A, B, C, D, ...>::type == std::tuple<B, D, A, C, ...>`, where `IsEmpty<B>::value == true`, `IsEmpty<D>::value == true`, and all others are false. In other words, partition a list of types (stably) according to some type predicate.

Comment: Yeah, stability is a good idea.  Moving things around that are equivalent to each other out of order is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on what Barry did.

> So from here I'd need a mapping meta-function to use the original
>   indices, how would I do that?

First, some helpers to facilitate index mapping. And because I'm lazy, I modified `typelist` slightly.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct typelist { 
    static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Args);
};

template<class T, std::size_t OldIndex, std::size_t NewIndex>
struct index_map_leaf {
    using type = T;
    static constexpr std::size_t old_index = OldIndex;
    static constexpr std::size_t new_index = NewIndex;
};

template<class... Leaves>
struct index_map : Leaves... {};
```

Given a properly built `index_map`, converting from old index to new index is simple, leveraging template argument deduction and overload resolution:

```
template<std::size_t OldIndex, std::size_t NewIndex, class T>
index_map_leaf<T, OldIndex, NewIndex> 
    do_convert_index(index_map_leaf<T, OldIndex, NewIndex>);

template<std::size_t OldIndex, class IndexMap>
using converted_index_t = decltype(do_convert_index<OldIndex>(IndexMap()));
```

`converted_index_t<OldIndex, IndexMap>::new_index` is, well, the new index.

To build the index map, we do it in in three steps. We start by transforming the types into type-index pairs.

```
template<class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
typelist<index_map_leaf<Ts, Is, 0>...>
    do_build_old_indices(typelist<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>);

template<class TL>
using build_old_indices =
    decltype(do_build_old_indices(TL(),  std::make_index_sequence<TL::size>()));
```

Next, we partition the pairs. We need a metafunction that applies another metafunction to its arguments' nested typedef `type` rather than the arguments themselves.

```
// Given a metafunction, returns a metafunction that applies the metafunction to
// its arguments' nested typedef type.
template<class F>
struct project_type {
    template<class... Args>
    using apply = typename F::template apply<typename Args::type...>;
};
```

Given this, partitioning a `typelist` of `index_map_leaf`s is simply `partition_t<LeafList, project_type<F>>`.

Finally, we transform the partitioned list, adding the new indices.

```
template<class... Ts, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t...Js>
typelist<index_map_leaf<Ts, Is, Js>...> 
    do_build_new_indices(typelist<index_map_leaf<Ts, Is, 0>...>,
                         std::index_sequence<Js...>);

template<class TL>
using build_new_indices =
   decltype(do_build_new_indices(TL(), std::make_index_sequence<TL::size>()));
```

Bringing it all together,

```
template<class TL, class F>
using make_index_map = 
    apply_t<quote<index_map>, build_new_indices<partition_t<build_old_indices<TL>, 
                                                            project_type<F>>>>;
```

---

With a little utility to convert the arguments of an arbitrary template to a type list:

```
template<template<class...> class T, class... Args>
typelist<Args...> do_as_typelist(typelist<T<Args...>>);

template<class T>
using as_typelist = decltype(do_as_typelist(typelist<T>()));
```

We can do the partitioning only once, by constructing the reordered tuple type directly from the `index_map`.

```
template<class Tuple, class F>
struct tuple_partitioner {
    using map_type = make_index_map<as_typelist<Tuple>, F>;
    using reordered_tuple_type = apply_t<project_type<quote<std::tuple>>,
                                         as_typelist<map_type>>;
    template<std::size_t OldIndex>
    using new_index_for = 
        std::integral_constant<std::size_t,
                               converted_index_t<OldIndex, map_type>::new_index>;
};
```

For example, given

```
using original_tuple = std::tuple<int, double, long, float, short>;
using f = quote<std::is_integral>;
using partitioner = tuple_partitioner<original_tuple, f>;
```

The following assertions hold:

```
static_assert(partitioner::new_index_for<0>() == 0, "!");
static_assert(partitioner::new_index_for<1>() == 3, "!");
static_assert(partitioner::new_index_for<2>() == 1, "!");
static_assert(partitioner::new_index_for<3>() == 4, "!");
static_assert(partitioner::new_index_for<4>() == 2, "!");
static_assert(std::is_same<partitioner::reordered_tuple_type,
                           std::tuple<int, long, short, double, float>>{}, "!");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e81b661322d4e4e6).

---

P.S. Here's my version of `filter`:

```
template<typename A, typename F>
using filter_one = std::conditional_t<F::template apply<A>::value,
                                      typelist<A>, typelist<>>;

template<typename F, typename... Args>
concat_t<filter_one<Args, F>...> do_filter(typelist<Args...>);

template <typename TL, typename F>
using filter_t = decltype(do_filter<F>(TL()));
```

Comment: I am really liking the `decltype(function_call())` style. Makes it a lot easier to write some of these metafunctions, although the actual name of the function gets lost in the verbiage of the return type.

Comment: @Barry, yeah, I was finding that too.  Might it be easier to read as `template <...> auto fn(...) -> ...`?  Dunno if that's much better.  I find reading template meta-code so hard to read all around.

Comment: Is the partition code going to move objects out of order that are considered the same?  I guess that's too much to ask eh?

Comment: @Adrian The partitioning is stable.

Comment: Tried to make a getter function but couldn't get the syntax right:  `template <std::size_t I, typename TP, typename...Ts>
auto
get(std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
{
    return std::get<TP::new_index_for<I>()>(t);
}
` where `TP` would be the the `tuple_partitioner`.  This should allow it to be used like `get<1, partitioner>(mytuple);`

Comment: @Adrian `template <std::size_t I, typename TP, typename...Ts> 
decltype(auto) get(std::tuple<Ts...>& t) { return std::get<TP::template new_index_for<I>::value>(t); }`

Answer (score 4):

First, let's start with the basics. We need a way to turn a template template (`std::tuple`) into a metafunction class:

```
template <template <typename...> class Cls>
struct quote {
    template <typename... Args>
    using apply = Cls<Args...>;
};
```

And a typelist:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct typelist { };
```

And something to go between them:

```
template <typename F, typename TL>
struct apply;

template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct apply<F, typelist<Args...>> {
    using type = typename F::template apply<Args...>;
};

template <typename F, typename TL>
using apply_t = typename apply<F, TL>::type;
```

So that given some typelist, we can just have:

```
using my_tuple = apply_t<quote<std::tuple>, some_typelist>;
```

Now, we just need a partitioner on some criteria:

```
template <typename TL, typename F>
struct partition {
    using type = concat_t<filter_t<TL, F>,
                          filter_t<TL, not_t<F>>
                          >;
};
```

Where `concat`:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct concat;

template <typename... Args>
using concat_t = typename concat<Args...>::type;

template <typename... A1, typename... A2, typename... Args>
struct concat<typelist<A1...>, typelist<A2...>, Args...> {
    using type = concat_t<typelist<A1..., A2...>, Args...>;
};

template <typename TL>
struct concat<TL> {
    using type = TL;
};
```

`filter`:

```
template <typename TL, typename F>
struct filter;

template <typename TL, typename F>
using filter_t = typename filter<TL, F>::type;

template <typename F>
struct filter<typelist<>, F> {
    using type = typelist<>;
};

template <typename A, typename... Args, typename F>
struct filter<typelist<A, Args...>, F> {
    using type = concat_t<
                     std::conditional_t<F::template apply<A>::value,
                                        typelist<A>,
                                        typelist<>>,
                     filter_t<typelist<Args...>, F>
                     >;
};
```

And `not_`:

```
template <typename F>
struct not_ {
    template <typename Arg>
    using apply = std::conditional_t<F::template apply<Args>::value,
                                     std::false_type,
                                     std::true_type>;
};
```

Which, given `some_typelist` of types that you want to put in your `tuple` becomes:

```
using my_tuple = apply_t<
    quote<std::tuple>, 
    partition_t<
        some_typelist,
        some_criteria_metafunc_class
    >>;
```

Comment: Wow.  It's going to take me a while to digest this. So from here I'd need a mapping meta-function to use the original indices, how would I do that?

Comment: @Adrian just don't use the indices. Use the type getters, those are easier to read anyway (you know what type `get<int>(t)` gives you without having to lookup `t`)

Comment: That only works if the types are different. This would be by no means a guarantee.

Comment: I probably would write `filter` differently.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah I'm not a fan of this, I'll come up with something better tmrw.